# Using AJAX to process SQL from within WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am in the process of trying to learn AJAX. For now, I want to read and write MySQL tables from within WordPress. There are lots of tutorials out there, but so far I haven't managed to get any of them to work. I'm sure it's because this is all new and I'm simply not understanding something basic about the process.
If I can get a very simple call to work, I'm sure I can expand on that and figure out what I need from there.
Here is what I'm working on currently.

Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wps_get_time', 'wps_get_time' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wps_get_time', 'wps_get_time' );
function wps_get_time() {
    $format = $_POST['format'];
    echo date( $format );
    die();
}

function sonata_script_includer() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-test.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script(' ajax-test' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sonata_script_includer' );
```

Javascript is in: (theme directory) '/js/ajax-test.js'

```
var format = 'U';
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin-ajax.php",
    data: { action: 'wps_get_time', format: format }
}).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
});
```

HTML is just a simple onclick event.

```
<button ... onclick="ajax-test()">
```

Edit: After posting this, I realized that my current code has nothing to do with SQL as stated in my Title. My goal is to process SQL queries, but currently I'm just trying to get a simple AJAX call to work. I'll add the SQL once I get something to work.

Comment: have you already looked at your network tab in your browser to see if your JQuery post call is actually sent to the server? https://www.section.io/blog/chrome-developer-tools-tutorial-network/

Comment: I hadn't, but I just did. No, nothing is happening.

Comment: try removing .done() and adding success:function(data){console.log(data)} after data:{}

Comment: no difference : (

Comment: I just discovered that under console I am getting "Ajax is not defined" and "wps_get_time is not defined". Also, I tried localizing admin-ajax with "wp_localize_script('admin-ajax', 'ajax', array('url'=> admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));" but it made no difference.

Comment: did you inlude jquery in your html template? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Yes, my header has: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and no other jquery calls. Although, in my page source, there is:<script type='text/javascript' src='http://starsonata.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script> which I haven't tracked down yet.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to say that I finally managed to get an AJAX call working. I abandoned the example listed above. I doubt it ever worked (as the author claimed), but my fidling with it probably didn't help.
Here is a listing of my working AJAX call.

This is based on info from. "https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/". It doesn't do much. You click on a radiobutton, then this code changes the radiobutton text. But it does it through ajax!

HTML

```
<form id="radioform">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="pref" checked="checked" name="book" type="radio" value="Sycamore Row" />Sycamore Row</td>
    <td>John Grisham</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="pref" name="book" type="radio" value="Dark Witch" />Dark Witch</td>
    <td>Nora Roberts</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

jQuery ( located in http://example.com/wp-content/js/myjquery.js )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".pref").change(function() {
    var this2 = this;
    $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {
        _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,
        action: "my_ajax_handler",
        title: this.value
        }, function(data) {
            $( "h2" ).eq( 1 ).html( data );
            this2.nextSibling.remove();
            $(this2).after("("+data+")");
        });
    });
});
```

Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {
    $title_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'SuperSecretNonce' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxScript',
        get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/myjquery.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxScript', 'my_ajax_obj', array(
       'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
       'nonce'    => $title_nonce,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
function my_ajax_handler() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'SuperSecretNonce' );
    $result = "Test String";
    wp_send_json( $result );
}
```

Now that I have a working example, it should be easy to expand it into whatever I need. Hopefully, this will help someone else who is strugling with making an AJAX call as well.

Thanks everyone for the help and encouragement!